# Trasladar una consulta sql a querybuilder

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Buenas Noches me gustaría trasladar la consulta sql al query builder de laravel.Gracias de antemano

```
select attendances.create_at , attendances.status
from lessons
INNER JOIN attendances
on attendances.lesson_id = lessons.id
INNER JOIN subjects
on subjects.id = lessons.subject_id
where lessons.term_id=1 and lessons.subject_id=3
```

Answer (score 1):

Esto debería funcionar:

```
$resultado = DB::table('lessons')
            ->join('attendances ', 'lessons.id', '=', 'attendances.lesson_id')
            ->join('subjects', 'lessons.subject_id', '=', 'subjects.id')
            ->where('lessons.term_id', 1) 
            ->where('lessons.subject_id', 3)
            ->select('attendances.create_at', 'attendances.status')
            ->get();
```

Si además tuvieras un modelo para lessons, bastaría con:

```
$resultado = Lessons::join('attendances ', 'lessons.id', '=', 'attendances.lesson_id')
            ->join('subjects', 'lessons.subject_id', '=', 'subjects.id')
            ->where('lessons.term_id', 1) 
            ->where('lessons.subject_id', 3)
            ->select('attendances.create_at', 'attendances.status')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Considero que la mejor forma es trabajando con **eager loading** para ello será necesario que tengas los siguientes modelos creados

- `Lesson`
- `Attendance`
- `Subject`

Y en el modelo llamado `Lesson` crear dos métodos con las relaciones así, considerando que trabajas las relaciones de **1:N**

Entiendo que una lección puede tener muchas asistencias y temas por eso le puse a los nombres la s final para que quede en plural

```
public function attendances()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Attendance::class);
}
```

Y una más asi

```
public function subjects()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Subject::class);
}
```

En caso de que la relación con temas sea de uno a uno, es decir una relación solo puede tener un tema entonces tú relación en lugar de tener `hasMany` debe de tener `hasOne` y quedar el nombre del método en singular

Finalmente puedas escribir tu consulta de este modo

```
$data = Lesson::with(['attendances', 'subjects'])
              ->where('lessons.term_id', 1)
              ->where('lessons.subject_id', 3)
              ->select(.......)
              ->get();
```

Lo que se hace es:

- Cargar las 2 relaciones que posee el modelo `Lesson` dentro de una estructura de *vector*
- Colocamos el doble `where`
- Hacemos un `select` de todas las columnas que deseamos
- Obtenemos los registros